# How to create a table in Ruby on Rails or change the migration order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing a Ruby on Rails app. I have created a model like so:

```
rails generate model Post user:references header:string body:text topic:string
```

And then I created a model User like so:

```
rails generate model User name:string email:string password:string
```

But running

```
db:migrate
```

Gives me the error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
```

So I guess I messed up with the order of the table creation and should have created the model User first and then migrate before creating the Post model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rename one of the two new migrations in `db/migrate/` to change the numeric timestamp in the filename, and thereby change the order they're run.

Comment: Be careful while changing timestamp of migration, it can ruin things badly and I won't suggest it.